# Selecting area of the screen with Python

Tags: python, screenshot

I'm developing a screen shot utility in Python. At the moment it is specifically for Linux. So far I have the ability to take a screen shot of the full desktop, and have it upload to Imgur, then copy the link to clipboard. Now I want to expand into functions such as screen shots of the active window, or of a specific selection. If anyone could help, I'd love to know what kind of module would work best for this, and how to implement such a module.

Comment: What exactly are you using right now to take screenshots?

Comment: How far did you get? I would need exactly such a program. Is it available?

Answer (score 2):

The functionality will depend on what you are using for image grabbing.

> With PIL

- http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagegrab.htm

> With GTK

To take a screenshot of active window :

- http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq23.039.htp

Also look at the pixbuf api

- http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk-pixbuf/
- http://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf-gdk-pixbuf.html

> Off topic

There are some screen cast tools: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/castro/1.0.4