# Is there a library in python that allows you to select a certain part of your screen?

Tags: python

Since in my place school's online i decided to work on a python script that will help me do math problems by allowing me to select a certain part of my screen to find the coordinates of where the math problem is located then it will take a screen shot of the math problem and the math problem only using the coordinates i found by selecting the area around the math problem, now i know how to do the solving and screenshooting part but i don't know how i can select an area in my window using python. So is there any library or api out there that will allow me to to select a part of my screen just like if it were photoshop? i have already seen the post [Selecting area of the screen with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895732/selecting-area-of-the-screen-with-python) and it would've answered my question but the link for taking a screenshot of an active window doesn't work so yeah..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting area of the screen with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895732/selecting-area-of-the-screen-with-python)

Comment: It would've been but for some reason the link for taking a screenshot for an active window isn't working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846947/9705687